# Python 3 - tkinter adding a minimize button

Tags: python-3.x, windows, tkinter

I would like to add a custom minimize button in ***###*** but don't really know how to.
I have tried looking for a bit but only found Python 2 results which no longer work for Python 3.
It would be best if it was possible for both linux and windows (with an os check at the start which I can do myself) and without the use of imported modules off the basic python modules.
Here is my current code:

```
from tkinter import *
import ctypes

root = Tk()
usr32 = ctypes.windll.user32
res1 = usr32.GetSystemMetrics(0)
res2 = usr32.GetSystemMetrics(1)

#-------------------------------

def ext():
    exit()


def minim():
    ###


root.resizable(0, 0)
root.geometry(str(int(res1 * 0.15)) + "x" + str(int(res2 * 0.1)))
root.overrideredirect(1)

back = Frame(root, bg='black')
back.pack_propagate(0)
back.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

b_Frame = Frame(back, bg="#505050")
b_Frame.place(x=0, y=0, anchor="nw", width=res1 * 0.15, height=res2 * 0.025)

Ext_but = Button(b_Frame, text="X", bg="#FF6666", fg="white", command=ext)
Ext_but.place(x=res1 - res1 * 0.8665, y=0, anchor="nw", width=res1 * 0.016, height=res2 * 0.025)

Min_but = Button(b_Frame, text="_", bg="#FF6666", fg="white", command=minim)
Min_but.place(x=res1 - res1 * 0.8825, y=0, anchor="nw", width=res1 * 0.016, height=res2 * 0.025)

#-------------------------------

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
root.wm_state("iconic")
```

For example a button that does this could be:

```
tk.Button(root, text = "Mimimize", command = lambda: root.wm_state("iconic")).pack()
```

So in your example it would be:

```
def minim():
    root.wm_state("iconic")
```

Uses standard modules (as requested). Tested in Windows 10 in Python 3.6, but it should work with all operating systems and Python versions.

Comment: Hello, that has worked with:
> root.overrideredirect(0)
But it gives me another issue when I maximize back, I would need a way to set it back to root.overrideredirect(1) only when maximized. How would that be done? (Sorry for my dumb questions, I am only starting with GUIs on python, thanx in advance).

Comment: @Marcel Barlik To clarify, do you mean maximized, or unminimized? (Filling the screen with the app vs. pressing the app in the bar)

Comment: It's okay now. I've found a way. Thanx for the help. :)